# How do I spend this prepaid debt mastercard with one cent on it?

Tags: debit-card, mastercard

AT&T decided they owed me money after changing cell phone providers.  They sent me a prepaid debt mastercard for what they felt they owed me in the amount of one cent.  How can I spend this?  I tried to load the value onto my amazon gift card, but there is a minimum of 50 cents for a transaction.  I know stores also have minimum transactions.  Is this even possible to spend?  I really just find it funny that they did it to begin with...evidence this is not a joke:
[image]

Comment: go to a supermarket and ask to split payment methods.

Comment: @littleadv can you do that on such a small amount?  The transaction fee is greater than what is on the card.

Comment: It's stupid, and they wasted more money on the card than they sent you, but it was probably cheaper to just send out every card than to 1) spend the money to craft and send you a letter saying it was not cost effective to reimburse you, 2) subdivide the refunds into cards and checks, or 2) ignore you silently and deal with calls wondering where there penny was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the bottom right of your scan. Convert the card into a bank transfer or paper check.

Comment: sounded like a great idea (wish I read the whole thing).  I tried to do it (out of amusement), but the site doesn't recognize the card and I have to contact support.  They probably disabled it realizing how stupid it was.  Now they can pay someone to answer my support request.

Answer (score 4):

At minimum wage the time you spent writing this question would have earned you far more than one cent. Throw the card away. It's not worth it to you.